# Ensure window focus before sending keys

Tags: vbscript, focus, sendkeys, wsh

I'm using a VBScript to `SendKeys` to a Cisco Client because it prompts for a username and password. However, I am having problems getting the command prompt focused.

I added `AppActivate` before every `SendKeys` command, but normal computer usage often breaks the focus in the time between these commands.

How can I ensure the command prompt has focus before sending keys?

```
Dim host, username, password, pathToClient
host = "host"
username = "username"
password = "password"
pathToClient = "C:\Program Files {(}x86{)}\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"

Set ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ws.run("TASKKILL.exe /F /IM vpnui.exe"), 0, false
ws.run("cmd.exe"), 2, false
WScript.Sleep 300
ws.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
ws.SendKeys """" & pathToClient & """ connect " & host & "~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
ws.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
ws.SendKeys(username & "~")
WScript.Sleep 50
ws.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
ws.SendKeys(password & "~")
ws.run("TASKKILL.exe /F /IM cmd.exe"), 0, false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) to solve my issue. Here's my code:

```
host := "my.host.domain"
username := "myUsername"
password := "myPassword"
pathToClient = "C:\...\vpncli.exe"

DetectHiddenWindows, on
Process, Close, vpnui.exe
run, cmd.exe,, Hide
Sleep 100
ControlSend,, %pathToClient% connect %host%{Enter}, ahk_exe cmd.exe
Sleep 1000
ControlSend,, %username%{Enter}, ahk_exe cmd.exe
Sleep 50
ControlSend,, %password%{Enter}, ahk_exe cmd.exe
;Process, Close, cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

With VBScript you can't. `AppActivate` is the only method available in VBScript to place the focus on a particular application, and it doesn't ensure the focus stays there. That's the exact reason why `SendKeys` shouldn't be used for automation anyway. Try something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) instead.

Or might setting [*Auto Connect on Start*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect31/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin31/ac03vpn.html#pgfId-1158027) be an option, since you're apparently using AnyConnect?

> Auto Connect on Start—AnyConnect, when started, automatically establishes a VPN connection with the secure gateway specified by the AnyConnect profile, or to the last gateway to which the client connected.

Comment: The client is still requiring a password on startup with those settings. I'll accept your answer if you get me headed in the right direction with AutoHotKey (preferably) or AutoIt.